# A "friend" changed Shift+Return to Caps Lock+Return. How can I change it back?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

My friend convinced me to allow him to change some of my key bindings.

Friend: "How often do you use Caps Lock?"

Anyway, now when I want to perform a newline without submitting a form, I have to do <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. This is very annoying because it turns Caps Lock on/off each time.

I have attempted to restore all defaults, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm going to restart again and hopefully that works, but I am beginning to doubt anything is going to work.

What am I missing here? How am I breaking this? I must be doing something very dumb but I can't see it. How can I change my settings back to the point where <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> does what it used to?

Comment: Ask your friend

Comment: I did, he tried and failed to fix it.

Comment: So he's even unable to tell you how he changed it in the first place?

Comment: He said that he went to Settings -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys, then changed Caps Lock Key: to Control and Control Key: to Caps Lock. He did these for both of my keyboards. I went restored defaults for both of my keyboards, but my shift key still doesn't seem to work. It works for his setup, which leads me to suspect that some other action was performed that I do not know of (which led me to ask my question).

Comment: It has been fixed! I don't understand how, but it magically is fixed now! (I'll accept Andrea's answer because it is relevant)

Comment: That would have been a much better problem description. If you just outline your current problem, where it would be totally unclear how you arrived at that spot, that leaves people guessing and that's not very constructive. In your case it was clear which changes created the problem, so those should be mentioned in the question. If you already tried something and it didn't work, then you should put that in your question as well, otherwise people might suggest something that you've already ruled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article on macRumors that fits your question:

[Changing Keyboard Shortcuts](http://guides.macrumors.com/Changing_Keyboard_Shortcuts)

All you need to do is:

`System preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts pane`

Look for the section you are interested to, and change it.